# Cert-Manager get certificate, but web browser shows "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate"

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I have an issue with Certificate from Let's Encrypt in Kubernetes in Azure AKS.
It seems to be valid in k8s, but web browsers shows "Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate". Following steps from https://cert-manager.io/docs/troubleshooting/ to describe my state:

`kubectl get certificates --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE   NAME         READY   SECRET       AGE
gap         tls-secret   True    tls-secret   5h29m
```

`kubectl get CertificateRequests --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE   NAME               APPROVED   DENIED   READY   ISSUER             REQUESTOR                                          AGE
gap         tls-secret-h8xvm   True                True    letsencrypt-prod   system:serviceaccount:ingress-basic:cert-manager   5h31m
```

`kubectl get clusterissuer --all-namespaces`

```
NAME               READY   AGE
letsencrypt-prod   True    5h45m
```

`kubectl describe clusterissuer letsencrypt-prod`

```
...
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:            aaa@company.com
    Preferred Chain:
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-prod
    Server:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      http01:
        Ingress:
          Class:  nginx
          Pod Template:
            Metadata:
            Spec:
              Node Selector:
                kubernetes.io/os:  linux
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Registered Email:  aaa@company.com
    Uri:                    https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/XXXXXXXX
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-09-07T15:05:07Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

`kubectl get order --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE   NAME                         STATE   AGE
gap         tls-secret-h8xvm-907122039   valid   5h38m
```

`kubectl describe order -n gap tls-secret-h8xvm-907122039`

```
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    my.app.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt-prod
  Request:  XXXXXXXXX
Status:
  Authorizations:
    Challenges:
      Token:        XXXXXXXXXXX
      Type:         http-01
      URL:          https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/XXX/YYY
    Identifier:     dev01.got-dev.ligenius.app
    Initial State:  valid
    URL:            https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/XXX
    Wildcard:       false
  Certificate:      XXXXXXX
  Finalize URL:     https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/YYY/ZZZ
  State:            valid
  URL:              https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/YYY/ZZZ
Events:             <none>
```

`kubectl get challenges --all-namespaces`

```
No resources found
```

Is it ok that challenge doesn't exist?

---

Update 1

Ingress definition

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: XXX-chart
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: xxx-chart-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: xxx-chart
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: RELEASE-NAME
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "1.16.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "my.app.com"
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: "my.app.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: "yyy-svc"
                port:
                  number: 80
          - ... more path definition
```

curl -k https://my.app.com/

```html
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like ingress nginx return default 404 page, but it shouldn't matter for certificate instalation. The `yyy-svc` and other services are up and running.

---

Kubernetes server `1.22.6`

ingress-nginx/controller `v1.3.1`

cert-manager `v1.9.1`

Any thought what is misconfigured?
Earlier it worked for cert-manager v0.16.1, after upgrade to 1.9.1 and solving https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/3501 it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: when you see that, it usually means you're ingress controller is serving it's default certificate and not your cert-manager certificate. what does your ingress definition look like? (also, yes, it's normal for the challenges to be deleted after they've completed)

Comment: @ericfossas Added Ingress definition to the question. Good to know that it is ok for challenges to be deleted after they've completed. Any other idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In Ingress the annotation: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` was missing. I removed it some time ago because of some changes in cluster and now it's needed again.

Comment: But again I have your problem, despite adding that annotation.